# Memory errors while trying balance binary search tree?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, free, tree-balancing

I have an insertion function for a BST, which also calls and checks if a node is balanced. If it is not I call rotation function on the node. This is where the problem is -> up till then my program worked fine, however, after adding that function my program throws out errors. I have only written the leftrotate function for now because I am testing on a case that only requires left rotation, therefore the rightrotate now being there is not the problem for now. This is my insertion function

```
 Tnode* insertnode(Tnode* root, int key)
 {
   if (root == NULL)
    {
      Tnode* child = (Tnode*)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
      child->left = NULL;
      child->right = NULL;
      child->key = key;
      child->balance = 0;
      return child;
    }
    if (root->key < key)
    {
      root->right = insertnode(root->right,key);
    }
    else if (root->key >= key)
    {
      root->left = insertnode(root->left,key);
    }
    if (balance(root) > 1 || balance(root)  < -1)
    {
      if (balance(root) == -2)
      {
        *edit* root = leftrotate(root);
      }
      else
      {
        //rightrotate(root);
      }
    }
    return root;
  }
```

The criteria for balance is this: the absolute difference between the left subtree and right subtree of a node must not be greater than 1. This is my left rotate function:

```
 *edit*Tnode* leftrotate(Tnode *root)
 {
   Tnode * temproot = root;
   root = root->right;
   root->left = temproot;
   temproot->right = NULL;
   return root; *edit*
 }
```

This is the function that frees the tree:

```
  void freetree(Tnode * root)
  {
    if(root == NULL)
    {
      return;
    }
    freetree(root->left);
    freetree(root->right);
    free(root);
    return;
```

However, all blocks are not freed and the tree doesnt seem to balance itself correctly. This is the valgrind report:

```
==3704== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3704==     in use at exit: 192 bytes in 8 blocks
==3704==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 3 frees, 808 bytes allocated
==3704==
==3704== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3704==    definitely lost: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==3704==    indirectly lost: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==3704==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3704==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3704==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3704== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3704==
==3704== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3704== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any tips?
Edit: minimal main, file I'm opening is a binary file. 'i' refers to instruction to insert.

```
      FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2],"rb");
      if (fp2 == NULL)
      {
        printf("%d\n",-1);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

      int key = 0;
      char placeh;
      Tnode * root = (Tnode*)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
      fread(&root->key,sizeof(int),1,fp2);

      root->left = NULL;
      root->right = NULL;
      root->balance = 0;
      fread(&placeh,sizeof(char),1,fp2);
      while (1)
      {
        fread(&key,sizeof(int),1,fp2);
        fread(&placeh,sizeof(char),1,fp2);
        if (feof(fp2))
        {
          break;
        }
        if (placeh == 'i')
        {
          //printf("%d ",key);
          insertnode(root,key);
        }
      }
      printtree(root);
      freetree(root);
      fclose(fp2);
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `root = root->right;` That changes a **local** variable. It does not change the caller's copy of `root`.

Comment: @kaylum thanks.how would I acutally  make the change I want? I tried doing  it within the insert function itself but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Return `root` or pass in a `Tnode **root_pointer`

Comment: @kaylum I have edited the code in the post to return root. However I am still getting the same errors. Can you spot anything that might be causing it ?

Comment: It's not enough to return it. You need to use it in the caller right? `root=leftrotate(root);`

Comment: @kaylum thank you. I tried that .. but it it's still the same error. If I comment out that function call, my program works fine. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Difficult to help you further without a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Need to be able to see how you are calling all those functions and be able to repro myself. Suggest you edit your post to put in a minimal `main`. And please remove the line numbers as that makes it difficult for others to copy your code to try.

Comment: @kaylum I have edited the post, to include the main. Do you want me to include the input file as well?

Comment: @kaylum sorry not sure if you saw my previous comments or my edit, but do you have any suggestions?